# confused about "fill_parent" in TableLayout

Tags: android, layout, tablelayout

First, xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns = "1">

        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:text = "Test Layout:"
                android:id = "@+id/LayoutTextView01"
                android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
                android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                android:textColor = "@color/red_bg" />
            <EditText
                android:text = ""
                android:id = "@+id/EditText01"
                android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
                android:layout_height = "wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:gravity = "right">
            <Button
                android:text = "test"
                android:id = "@+id/layoutButton01"
                android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
                android:layout_height = "wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

My question is:

1.`fill_parent` means fill all the spaces of its parent container. And ***the parent of Button*** should have the same size of ***the parent of EditView***, and for ***Button*** and ***EditView*** both set android:layout_width to "fill_parent", they should have the same size, just like that:

```
________ ___________________
|_______| |__________________|
              __________________
             |__________________|
```

But the result is like that:

```
________ ___________________
|_______| |__________________|
                         ___________
                         |__________|
```

why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it helps if you add `android:layout_column="1"` to your `button tag`.

By the way. How can i commend questions instead of submitting an answer?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. IOW android only  picks the button which belongs to the column 0 to right, so the button has the same size as TextView, right? BTW  there is a link "add comment" below every question, by which you can add a comment. and in the left of every question, there is a pentagram, you can click it to favorite it. and also a △▽, by which help you can up or down a question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your button thinks it is in column 0.  If you add another element it will be in column 1 and have the same width.  I tried it out and this should give you the results you were looking for.

```
<TableRow android:gravity = "right">
        <TextView
            android:text = ""
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content" />
        <Button
            android:text = "test"
            android:id = "@+id/layoutButton01"
            android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content" />
</TableRow>
```

Happy coding.